# Invert list of periods

Tags: java, time, java-8

I have a list of periods - each period contains startTime and endTime (as a timestamp).
I want to create a list which will contain missing gaps in given range.

Example:
from `100` to `500` for given list:

- `Range[150, 200]`
- `Range[230, 400]`

It will produce a list:

- `Range[100, 150]`
- `Range[200, 230]`
- `Range[400, 500]`

I created a simple algorithm which is iterating my input list and creates valid result table, but I wonder if I can do the same using `java8` time API or is there an external library for that.

Comment: Your In and Output don't seem to make sense. As you stated you're filling the gaps. Shouldn't you have a much larger output table

Comment: Gaps in given range `100-500`

Comment: Also the output is invalid, as all the numbers exist in the ranges. For example 400 overlaps 400, 150 overlaps 150 and so on

Comment: @ByeBye You will probably end up with the same algorithm, with the additional complexity of dealing with dates and times.

Comment: You might have more luck getting a relevant answer by posting your current code on the [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Looking at the `java.time` package I don't think there are any relevant classes to handle your usecase though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution using my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J). I have assumed that your timestamps are to be modelled as "milliseconds since Unix epoch", but you are free to use any other type. Time4J knows many different types of date- or time-related intervals and offers various methods to calculate interferences of intervals, here the [complement of an interval collection](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/IntervalCollection.html#withComplement-net.time4j.range.ChronoInterval-).

```
// define/create your intervals
    MomentInterval i1 =
        MomentInterval.between(Instant.ofEpochMilli(150), Instant.ofEpochMilli(200));
    MomentInterval i2 =
        MomentInterval.between(Instant.ofEpochMilli(230), Instant.ofEpochMilli(400));

// collect the intervals into an interval-collection
    IntervalCollection<Moment> ic =
        IntervalCollection.onMomentAxis().plus(Arrays.asList(i1, i2));

// define/create the outer time window
    MomentInterval window =
        MomentInterval.between(Instant.ofEpochMilli(100), Instant.ofEpochMilli(500));

// create/calculate the complement of the interval collection
    ic.withComplement(window)
      .getIntervals()
      .forEach(
        i ->
            System.out.println(
                "Range[" 
                + i.getStart().getTemporal().toTemporalAccessor().toEpochMilli() 
                + ", "
                + i.getEnd().getTemporal().toTemporalAccessor().toEpochMilli() 
                + "]"
            )
      );
```

> Range[100, 150]
>
> Range[200, 230]
>
> Range[400, 500]

By the way, Time4J uses the half-open-approach for moment/instant-intervals meaning that the end boundary of such intervals is excluded. Therefore, I would rather choose the open bracket ")" instead of "]" but have here closely followed your question.

Answer (score 4):

Using a list of individual range boundaries, you can construct that using a complete set that includes min and max:

I'm using array[int, int], which should be easy to translate into your `Range` object.

The logic is simple: using only the range boundary numbers, make a complete set and then make pairs of all consecutive boundaries. For that, a sorted list of all (distinct) numbers, including the missing ranges is first created...

```
List<Integer> flat = Arrays.<int[]>asList(new int[] { 150, 200 }, 
                         new int[] { 230, 400 }).stream()
                          .flatMap(e -> Arrays.asList(e[0], 
                        e[1]).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> fullRange = new ArrayList<>();
fullRange.add(100);
fullRange.add(500);
fullRange.addAll(flat);

List<Integer> all = fullRange.stream()
                     .distinct()
                     .sorted()
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());


System.out.println(
      IntStream.range(0, all.size())
               .filter(i -> i < -1 + all.size()) #Excluding the last element
               .mapToObj(index -> Arrays.asList( //You can create Range objects here
                                   all.get(index), 
                                   all.get(index + 1))
                )
               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

This outputs:

```
[[100, 150], [150, 200], [200, 230], [230, 400], [400, 500]]
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution could be like below. for this i defined some classes and functions.

**Class Range** :

```
class Range{
  private int start;
  private int end;
}
```

**class RangeInfo**:

```
class RangeInfo {
    private List<Range> ranges;
    private int newStart;
    private int newEnd;
  }
```

**function1:**

This function create new `Range` object from two `Range` object.

```
 BiFunction<Range,Range,Range> function1 = (r1,r2)->new Range(r1.getEnd(),r2.getStart());
```

**function**

This function has two parameter that they are List`(Range[150, 200] and Range[230, 400])` and `Range (100, 500)` and return List of new Range.

```
BiFunction<List<Range>,Range,List<Range>> function = (r1, pair)->{ // you can use new Pair(100,500) instead of Range object
  result.add(new Range(pair.getStart(),r1.get(0).getStart()));
  IntStream.range(0, r1.size() - 1).mapToObj(i -> function1.apply(r1.get(i), r1.get(i + 1))).forEachOrdered(result::add);
  result.add(new Range(r1.get(r1.size()-1).getEnd(),pair.getEnd()));
  result.addAll(r1);
 return result;
};
```

and finally create Range and sort them like below.

```
function.apply(ranges,new Range(100,500))
   .stream()
   .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Range::getStart))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[***Demo***](http://tpcg.io/jcGgQ7)

Answer (score 0):

This would be the code in native Java

**Code**

```
public final class RangesCalculator {

private static final String START_RANGE = "100";
private static final String END_RANGE = "500";


public static List<Range> invertRange(List<Range> ranges) {

    List<Range> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Range range : ranges) {
        if (toReturn.isEmpty()) {
            if (!START_RANGE.equals(range.getStart())) {
                toReturn.add(Range.newBuilder().setStart(START_RANGE).setEnd(range.getStart()).build());
            }
        } else {
            Range lastRange = toReturn.get(toReturn.size() - 1);
            lastRange.setEnd(range.getStart());
        }
        if (!END_RANGE.equals(range.getEnd())) {
            toReturn.add(Range.newBuilder().setStart(range.getEnd()).setEnd(END_RANGE).build());
        }
    }

    return toReturn.stream().filter(range -> !range.getStart().equals(range.getEnd())).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

}